# What is the analogue of iptables' exclamation mark in UFW?

Tags: linux, iptables, ufw

What would be the analogue of this iptables commad in ufw?

```
iptables -A OUTPUT ! -d 5.5.5.5 -j DROP
```

What is the analogue of exclamation mark in ufw? In other words, how to match all IP addresses excluding the specified one?
Thanks!

Comment: For the record, it can be put in the way of `iptables -A OUTPUT -d 5.5.5.5 -j ACCEPT; iptables -A OUTPUT -j DROP`...

Comment: The negation of "allow" is "deny" and vice versa. Two rules as in the above comment.

Comment: @harrymc, Then how do I restrict outgoing connections to only one ip address using ufw if I don't want to block all outgoing connections by default? I have many network interfaces and I only one of them is network interface connected to the Internet (eth0). I want to deny all outgoing packets that is directed to any ip excluding `5.5.5.5` (for example) through eth0 interface. It means that outgoing traffic to any interface except eth0 is allowed. I would do it `iptables -A OUTPUT ! -o eth0 -j ACCEPT`, but it also requires using exclamation mark in iptables.